# Is it possible to add an entire domain to suppression list in SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ses, suppression

I want to block users in my app from interacting with specific domains, so I added emails belonging to those domain to my AWS SES suppression lists, but my users keep create contacts of different individuals belonging to the same domains I want to block.

Is there a way to add an entire domain to the suppression list? Like a wild-card for example: %@domain.com